# Zoom still show original image after switching new image from thumbnail

Tags: javascript

I use Image Zoom from [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_image_zoom.asp), code as follows:

```js
function imageZoom(imgID, resultID) {
  var img, lens, result, cx, cy;
  img = document.getElementById(imgID);
  result = document.getElementById(resultID);
  lens = document.createElement("DIV");
  lens.setAttribute("class", "img-zoom-lens");
  img.parentElement.insertBefore(lens, img);
  cx = result.offsetWidth / lens.offsetWidth;
  cy = result.offsetHeight / lens.offsetHeight;
  result.style.backgroundImage = "url('" + img.src + "')";
  result.style.backgroundSize = (img.width * cx) + "px " + (img.height * cy) + "px";
  lens.addEventListener("mousemove", moveLens);
  img.addEventListener("mousemove", moveLens);
  lens.addEventListener("touchmove", moveLens);
  img.addEventListener("touchmove", moveLens);
  result.style.display = "none";

  function moveLens(e) {
    var pos, x, y;
    e.preventDefault();
    pos = getCursorPos(e);
    x = pos.x - (lens.offsetWidth / 2);
    y = pos.y - (lens.offsetHeight / 2);
    if (x > img.width - lens.offsetWidth) {x = img.width - lens.offsetWidth;}
    if (x < 0) {x = 0;}
    if (y > img.height - lens.offsetHeight) {y = img.height - lens.offsetHeight;}
    if (y < 0) {y = 0;}
    lens.style.left = x + "px";
    lens.style.top = y + "px";
    result.style.backgroundPosition = "-" + (x * cx) + "px -" + (y * cy) + "px";
  }

  function getCursorPos(e) {
    var a, x = 0, y = 0;
    e = e || window.event;
    a = img.getBoundingClientRect();
    x = e.pageX - a.left;
    y = e.pageY - a.top;
    x = x - window.pageXOffset;
    y = y - window.pageYOffset;
    return {x : x, y : y};
  }
}

imageZoom("myimage", "myresult");
```

And I use the following simple code to switch images:

```js
function change_img(img_src) {
  document.getElementsByName("goods_img")[0].src=img_src;
}
```

My url: https://cn.angelcorp.net/shop/goods.php?id=9
You may click the thumbnail image with flag, but the zoom still show original image without flag.
Thank you.

Comment: please wrap your code \``` for readability

Comment: I think we can show a bit of leniency to a user who just joined and is asking their very first question :) thanks theBittor for making the edit. And @scott_ease welcome to SO, please take a moment to familiarize yourself with the code formatting tools we: https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got to change the background of `myresult` to the `img_src` as well.
Change the function to this

```js
function change_img(img_src) {
document.getElementsByName("goods_img")[0].src=img_src;
document.getElementById("myresult").style = `background-image: url("${img_src}"); background-size: 468.846px 468.846px; display: none; background-position: -256.846px -256.846px;`;
}
```